# Sorting out rows in a csv not working as planned

Tags: python, csv

I've been having some problems with what seems to be straightforward.
I have a list of column values, that if matched, I want excluded from a csv [saved from Python in XLS mode]. I'd had problems with this earlier and thought I had found a clumsy work around - but I seem to bee mistaken.

Edit: the CSV has 9 columns in each row. 
The types are: text, int, text, text, int, text, text, int, text

Basically, I have a list: 
[14, 817],[14, 607],[14, 514],[8, 31],[8, 654],[8, 1045]

and if the row values match both e.g. row[1] == 14 and row[4] == 817, the row should be skipped. Otherwise it should be written to a new csv.

Basically:

```
for something in ([14, 817],[14, 607],[14, 514],[8, 31],[8, 654],[8, 1045]):
     check1a = int(something[0])
     check2a = int(something[1])
     check1b = int(row[1])
     check2b = int(row[4])

    if (check1a == check1b) and (check2a == check2b):
        print row
        #or 'pass' in non-debugging mode
    else:
        thecsv.writerow(row)
```

I can see from the output that matches are being made. But when I checked the file, there were still matches. Also, in my earlier filtering attempts, resulting in the file being read from, most but not all (inexplicably) duplicates were filtered out. A visual inspection didn't clear up why some weren't filtered out.

Comment: What is `row`? What value does it contain?

Comment: The row has six chances to get written to thecsv; all it has to do is not match one of the items in your for loop... you'll note that it cannot match all of them, so it will always get written, and in fact it will get written multiple times.

Comment: Doh! I'd switched the code from a positive match situation without thinking about it! 
I need to think about changing the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something if there is never a match, use a break and put the `else` on the `for` not on the `if`. Here's a [brief overview](http://psung.blogspot.com/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html).

For example, if I have a small list of some states and I want to print only the ones not containing the letter `b` or `c`,

```
data = ['alabama', 'alaska', 'arizona', 'arkansas', 'california', 'georgia']
for state in data:
    for letter in ['b', 'c']:
        if letter in state: # or whatever condition would be a match
            break
    else:
        print state
```

The output:

```
alaska
arizona
arkansas
georgia
```

In your case, assuming you have already defined `row`, you want

```
for something in ([14, 817],[14, 607],[14, 514],[8, 31],[8, 654],[8, 1045]):
     check1a = int(something[0])
     check2a = int(something[1])
     check1b = int(row[1])
     check2b = int(row[4])

    if (check1a == check1b) and (check2a == check2b):
        print row
        break
        #or 'pass' in non-debugging mode
else:
    thecsv.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I'll have to try to remember that "for" and "else" combo. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the above answer. I was also thinking something along the lines of:

```
skipme = [14, 817],[14, 607],[14, 514],[8, 31],[8, 654],[8, 1045]
check1b = int(row[1])
check2b = int(row[4])
matchpair = [check1b, check2b]
if matchpair not in skipme:
         thecsv.writerow(row)
```

[Edited in deference to comments.]

Comment: You wouldn't have to pass if you used ``not in``.